# DVD wont mount Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mount

I can't seem to be able to mount my optical drive.  I have tried numerous solutions from this site with no results. I am not able to see the device inside the file browser either.  There is a DVD in the drive.  I am running 12.04 on an HP g60-235dx portable. I have a link below to the specs.  I will also list what I have tried (that I can find back right now.)  I know the drive is functioning, because just before Windows 7 crashed and my MBR went fubar I was watching movies just fine.  I am fairly new to linux, so don't assume I know anything.  Ok, so here is what I have tried:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list
sudo apt-get --quiet update
sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring
sudo apt-get --quiet update
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

`dmesg | grep sr0` (no output)

`apt-get install libdvdnav4` (already installed, and up to date)

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh

ls -l  /dev/cdrom /dev/cdrw /dev/dvd /dev/dvdrw /dev/scd0 /dev/sr0
ls: cannot access /dev/scd0: No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 Sep 10 03:51 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 Sep 10 03:51 /dev/cdrw -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 Sep 10 03:51 /dev/dvd -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 Sep 10 03:51 /dev/dvdrw -> sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Sep 10 03:51 /dev/sr0


wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW TS-L633M'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  

sudo lshw optical

 *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: CDDVDW TS-L633M
                vendor: TSSTcorp
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/dvdrw
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: 0200
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc


sudo lshw | grep cdrom

*-cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

Spec sheet for portable:

http://www.cnet.com/laptops/hp-g60-235dx/4507-3121_7-33496192.html

If you need any more information than all of that... please let me know.

*Updates*

running sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks, logging out, and logging back in resulted in an error message saying 'internal error.'

running  udisks --mount /dev/sr0 with a disc in the drive returned: 'Mount failed: Error mounting: mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0'

running wodim --prcap dev=/dev/sr0 with no disk in the drive returns:

```
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'TSSTcorp'
Identification : 'CDDVDW TS-L633M '
Revision       : '0200'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing

  Does read Mode 2 Form 1 blocks
  Does read Mode 2 Form 2 blocks
  Does read digital audio blocks
  Does restart non-streamed digital audio reads accurately
  Does support Buffer-Underrun-Free recording
  Does read multi-session CDs
  Does read fixed-packet CD media using Method 2
  Does not read CD bar code
  Does read R-W subcode information
  Does not return R-W subcode de-interleaved and error-corrected
  Does read raw P-W subcode data from lead in
  Does return CD media catalog number
  Does return CD ISRC information
  Does support C2 error pointers
  Does not deliver composite A/V data

  Does play audio CDs
  Number of volume control levels: 256
  Does support individual volume control setting for each channel
  Does support independent mute setting for each channel
  Does not support digital output on port 1
  Does not support digital output on port 2

  Loading mechanism type: tray
  Does support ejection of CD via START/STOP command
  Does not lock media on power up via prevent jumper
  Does allow media to be locked in the drive via PREVENT/ALLOW command
  Is not currently in a media-locked state
  Does not support changing side of disk
  Does not have load-empty-slot-in-changer feature
  Does not support Individual Disk Present feature

  Maximum read  speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current read  speed:  1412 kB/s (CD   8x, DVD  1x)
  Maximum write speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current write speed:     0 kB/s (CD   0x, DVD  0x)
  Rotational control selected: CLV/PCAV
  Buffer size in KB: 2048
  Copy management revision supported: 1
  Number of supported write speeds: 0

Supported CD-RW media types according to MMC-4 feature 0x37:
  Does write multi speed       CD-RW media
  Does write high  speed       CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed  CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed+ CD-RW media
```

running sudo lshw -c disk with a disc in the drive returns:

```
*-disk                  
   description: ATA Disk
   product: FUJITSU MHZ2320B
   vendor: Fujitsu
   physical id: 0
   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: 8909
   serial: K618T913E9LE
   size: 298GiB (320GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=dfb6d394
  *-cdrom
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: CDDVDW TS-L633M
   vendor: TSSTcorp
   physical id: 1
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/cdrw
   logical name: /dev/dvd
   logical name: /dev/dvdrw
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: 0200
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 status=busy
  *-disk
   description: SCSI Disk
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sdb
```

Comment: You list the output of a bunch of diagnostics. Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see where you describe what you do that actually fails, or what the symptom of failure is (error message?). Have you tried reading a data DVD (not a video DVD) on linux on this machine? Have you tried reading a data CD? When you describe the problem as "won't mount," that doesn't quite make sense to me. "Mount" normally means that you make a filesystem accessible; that's not what you're trying to do here, because it's not a data DVD with a filesystem on it.

Comment: I'm trying to watch a DVD, burn discs, and just use the drive in general. Nothing I can find is getting it to do that.  nothing happens when I enter a data cd or dvd either, I have a bunch of photos burned to a disc that I cant access.  the drive never shows up to the left side when browsing files.

Comment: @Mik I'm running Nautilus 3.4.2, I dont see anywhere to change that setting

Comment: The drive is now showing up in Disk Utility, but it still says 'No Media' when there is a disc in the drive, and I still cannot do anything at all with the drive.

Comment: @CyborgGold don't worry about my other comment- I forgot you were running Nautilus. You could try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks` and log out and in again and then put your disk in and see if it mounted automatically. Are you able to mount the disk manually? Try `udisks --mount /dev/sr0` if this is your device name. Also try `wodim --prcap dev=/dev/sr0` (with no disk in the drive).

Comment: Also run `sudo lshw -c disk` with a disk in the drive and it will give you more information as will the other wodim command I mentioned above.

Comment: @ mik I have updated the question to reflect the results of running those 4 commands.

Comment: @CyborgGold I'll have to think of something else as those commands were useful for me a while ago.

Comment: What was the filesystem in the DVD? Did you test the drive using a CD?

Comment: I have tried several DVDs, NTFS data DVD with photos, a burned Win 7 install disc, and a couple different commercially made movies.  I dont currently have any CDs to try it with.

Comment: so... am i totally boned here or what?

Comment: Still need an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following terminal commands with a disk in the drive:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

or more simply

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

If you get an error message to the effect of "no media in drive" the most likely reason is a faulty drive.  Unfortunately dvd/cd drives are a lot more fragile than most people realise - a piece of fluff or a scratch on the lens can render them useless.  Even worse, laptop drives that have the lens on the carriage that is ejected from the device leave them very susceptible to physical damage.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hardware problem. Try mounting it manually

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom 
cd /mnt
ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this post in another answer but it is actually quite simple:

> A lot of people have had this problem, as I first did with the dvd and
>   cd mounting. You have to make a directory for the folder within media.
>   Be sure to run as root.
>
> ```
> sudo -s
>
> cd mkdir /media/[folder_name]
> ```
>
> If you have any error regarding read/write issues you will have to
>   chmod
>
> *Warning, If You do not know what you are doing I would suggest NOT doing this!*
>
> ```
> sudo -s
>
> cd /media
>
> chmod ugo+rwx
> ```
>
> I hope this helped! The main problem is that the drive will not
>   unmount itself after inserting a disk. Creating a directory solves
>   this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -s
cd mkdir /media/[folder_name]
```

If you have any error regarding read/write issues you will have to chmod :

*Warning, If You do not know what you are doing I would suggest NOT doing this!*

```
sudo -s
cd /media
chmod ugo+rwx
```

I hope this helped! The main problem is that the drive will not unmount itself after inserting a disk. Creating a directory solves this problem.

returns:

> root@Lexington:(unreachable)/# cd /media
>
> root@Lexington:/media# ls
>
> root@Lexington:/media# sudo mkdir dvd-drive
>
> root@Lexington:/media# chmod ugo+rwx
>
> chmod: missing operand after `ugo+rwx